# Large 2d array in C

Tags: c, arrays, list

I try to solve linear optimization problem of 4 variables and 600000 constraints.
I need to generate a large input. So I need `A[600000][4]` for constraint's coefficents and `b[600000]` for the right part. Here is a code to generate 600000 constraints.

```
int i, j;
int numberOfInequalities = 600000;
double c[4];
double result[4];;
double A[numberOfInequalities][4], b[numberOfInequalities];

printf("\nPreparing test: 4 variables, 600000 inequalities\n");
A[0][0] = 1.0; A[0][1] = 2.0; A[0][2] = 1.0; A[0][3] = 0.0; b[0] = 10000.0;
A[1][0] = 0.0; A[1][1] = 1.0; A[1][2] = 2.0; A[1][3] = 1.0; b[1] = 10000.0;
A[2][0] = 1.0; A[2][1] = 0.0; A[2][2] = 1.0; A[2][3] = 3.0; b[2] = 10000.0;
A[3][0] = 4.0; A[3][1] = 0.0; A[3][2] = 1.0; A[3][3] = 1.0; b[3] = 10000.0;
c[0]=1.0; c[1]=1.0; c[2]=1.0; c[3]=1.0;
for( i=4; i< 100000; i++ )
{
    A[i][0] = (12123*i)%104729;
    A[i][1] = (47*i)%104729;
    A[i][2] = (2011*i)%104729;
    A[i][3] = (7919*i)%104729;
    b[i] = A[i][0] + 2*A[i][1] + 3*A[i][2] + 4* A[i][3] + 1 + (i%137);
}
A[100000][0] = 0.0; A[100000][1] = 6.0; A[100000][2] = 1.0;
A[100000][3] = 1.0; b[100000] = 19.0;
for( i=100001; i< 200000; i++ )
{
    A[i][0] = (2323*i)%101111;
    A[i][1] = (74*i)%101111;
    A[i][2] = (2017*i)%101111;
    A[i][3] = (7915*i)%101111;
    b[i] = A[i][0] + 2*A[i][1] + 3*A[i][2] + 4* A[i][3] + 2 + (i%89);
}
A[200000][0] = 5.0; A[200000][1] = 2.0; A[200000][2] = 0.0;
A[200000][3] = 1.0; b[200000] = 13.0;
for( i=200001; i< 300000; i++ )
{
    A[i][0] = (23123*i)%100003;
    A[i][1] = (47*i)%100003;
    A[i][2] = (2011*i)%100003;
    A[i][3] = (7919*i)%100003;
    b[i] = A[i][0] + 2*A[i][1] + 3*A[i][2] + 4* A[i][3] + 2 + (i%57);
}
A[300000][0] = 1.0; A[300000][1] = 2.0; A[300000][2] = 1.0;
A[300000][3] = 3.0; b[300000] = 20.0;
A[300001][0] = 1.0; A[300001][1] = 0.0; A[300001][2] = 5.0;
A[300001][3] = 4.0; b[300001] = 32.0;
A[300002][0] = 7.0; A[300002][1] = 1.0; A[300002][2] = 1.0;
A[300002][3] = 7.0; b[300002] = 40.0;
for( i=300003; i< 400000; i++ )
{
    A[i][0] = (13*i)%103087;
    A[i][1] = (99*i)%103087;
    A[i][2] = (2012*i)%103087;
    A[i][3] = (666*i)%103087;
    b[i] = A[i][0] + 2*A[i][1] + 3*A[i][2] + 4* A[i][3] + 1;
}
for( i=400000; i< 500000; i++ )
{
    A[i][0] = 1;
    A[i][1] = (17*i)%999983;
    A[i][2] = (1967*i)%444443;
    A[i][3] = 2;
    b[i] = A[i][0] + 2*A[i][1] + 3*A[i][2] + 4* A[i][3] + (1000000.0/(double)i);
}
for( i=500000; i< 600000; i++ )
{
    A[i][0] = (3*i)%111121;
    A[i][1] = (2*i)%999199;
    A[i][2] = (2*i)%444443;
    A[i][3] = i;
    b[i] = A[i][0] + 2*A[i][1] + 3*A[i][2] + 4* A[i][3] + 1.3;
}
```

The problem is: it can't create such a large array, it just terminates at the run-time, BUT it works fine if I create no more than 200000 constraints.
I've tried to increase stack size to unlimited value, but it didn't help.
I've tried to use pointers like **A, but I get incorrect result in output.
P.S.
I use Ubuntu.
Any ideas?

Comment: You could use [dynamic memory allocation](/q/917783/2461638).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `numberOfInequalities` is a runtime constant, you could make it a `#define` and define `A` and `b` as global variables or `static` local variables:

```
#define numberOfInequalities 600000
static double A[numberOfInequalities][4], b[numberOfInequalities];
```

This will move these arrays from the 'stack' to the 'bss' segment.

A better solution is to allocate these arrays with `malloc`:

```
double (*A)[4] = malloc(numberOfInequalities * 4 * sizeof(double));
double *b = malloc(numberOfInequalities * sizeof(double));
```

This will cause these arrays to be allocated from the 'heap' memory.
Don't forget to free them before returning to the caller.

See http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/ for a brief explanation how memory is arranged in a typical C program

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but the article you link to is a little simplistic and does not explain why the stack is of limited depth.  On more recent OS versions and especially 64 bit versions, memory layout is more complicated.  Allocating so much memory from the stack is indeed problematic but the precise explanation is rather obscure.